# Sublime API: set_read_only isn't working

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I can't seem to insert into a view that I created via "open_file":

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, re, os.path

class ExtractToViewCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    view = sublime.active_window().open_file("/path/to/some/file/that/doesnt/exist/yet")
    view.set_read_only(False)
    print(view.is_read_only())         # prints True!
    e = view.begin_edit()
    view.insert(e, 0, "hello world")   # returns 0!
    view.end_edit(e)
```

My goal here is to create a plugin to extract the selected text to a new file. The insert works just fine when I change it to use `new_file` instead of `open_file`. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure the view is loaded? From the API docs

Note that as file loading is asynchronous, operations on the returned view won't be possible until its is_loading() method returns False.